# PHP upload filename in arabic showing special characters in folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, iconv, mb-convert-encoding

I am using CodeIgnitor PHP and uploading an excel file in a folder in IIS server.
For the files that have English naming convention is working file and uploading ok but whenever the files names come in Arabic for example:  اسم ملف العينة.xls after uploading on the folder it is showing like this Ø§Ø³Ù…_Ù…Ù„Ù_Ø§Ù„Ø¹ÙŠÙ†Ø©_1516170951.xlsx

My database and page all are set to UTF-8 with meta tag also.

I need it to show with the same Arabic name inside folder.
Any help!

Comment: _"Showing like this..."_ where? In Explorer? The result of `scandir()` / `glob()` / etc?

Comment: It is saving the file with the special characters as mentioned above.

Comment: Could you please re-read my question? You haven't answered it at all

Comment: Bro file is saved like „Ù_Ø§Ù„Ø¹ÙŠÙ†Ø©_1516170951.xlsx and in calling on browser it is showing Arabic file name and error come file not found.
Means file calling is correct but saving name format is not.

Comment: What application are you looking at that shows the incorrect file name?

Comment: It is a php based web application. I didn't get you completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are using windows OS. So, You are facing this type of issue.

I have also faced the same issue right now **(using PHP 5.3 and Codeigniter 2)**. Files named in English were uploading just fine and I was able to download them also. The reason it can`t work for Arabic because you are using Windows OS. All I know this has something to do with the windows file system,

> In the uploads folder you will see file names for Arabic files like
>   `"Ø§Ø³Ù…_Ù…Ù„Ù_Ø§Ù„Ø¹ÙŠÙ†Ø©_1516170951.xlsx"` but if you run **`scandir()`**
>   in php as mentioned by Phil you will see the Arabic names like "`اسم`
>   `ملف العينة.xls`".